# Regex match certain kind of paragraph

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like

```
1 example
2 example
3 example
```

where each line is separated by a new line. I am trying to find a way to match so that there has to be more than one line, and each line must contain a number followed by a string. There also has to be at least 2 lines.

This is what I have so far but its not working.

```
(\d* \w*(\n|$)){2,}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work for you:

```
string.match(/\d+ \w+[\n\r]+\d+ \w+/m);
```

Note the 'm' which specifies that it's okay to match across multiple lines.

**Edit** Looks like your expression is fine, just missing the "m".

Comment: How can I match the last line as well which won't have a new line?

Comment: Edited my expression. It's not as elegant but... :)